# Fire and Forget multiple methods in C#

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, nonblocking, fire-and-forget

I have an Azure function which would have the ability to call multiple API endpoints without waiting for the results from any of them.

The Azure function runs on a timer trigger and runs every 10 seconds.

All my API calls and parameters to call them are stored in a SQL table.  I want to make sure that the API calls are made without waiting for a particular call to be finished.

This is just a blueprint of what I'll be doing.

```
[FunctionName("FunctionScheduler")]
public static async Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("*/10 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("FUNCTION SCHEDULER STARTING ..");

    log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

    for(int i=0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() => ApiRef1(i, log));
        var taskref = await task;
    }
```

}

Currently ApiRef1() simply prints out the value of the variable i.  I get the expected output of printing numbers 0 to 19.  I want parallel executions of the ApiRef1() method which will eventually be replace by a method that looks like this.

```
private static void CallApi(string apiName, string apiEndpoint, string methodType, string authenticationType, IDictionary<int, string> parameters, ILogger log)
{
    try
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Call to API {apiName} started.." );

        // Call API
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Exception {ex.Message} occurred.." );
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this or will this method work?

Comment: If you're "firing and forgetting" tasks, why are you capturing each task's results (with `await`)? Or do you not need to do that any more?

Comment: This would be a good use case for [C# Discards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards)

Comment: @gunr2171. I do not need that. I can use  await Task.Run(() => ApiRef1(i, log));
That yields the same results.  But does this guarantee that is it a true fire and forget method

Comment: @DetectivePikachu  I wasn't aware of this.  I'll have to check it out.

Comment: @MAK, as far as I know, yes. Removing the line `var taskref = await task;` _"""should"""_ be all you need to do. Also make your method non-async.

Comment: You cannot have true fire and forget in this instance, as you need to ensure the completion of the task(s) before the Azure Function is terminated. I'd store each task that is created for each iteration in a list and wait the completion of all tasks `Task.WhenAll(IEnumerable<Task>).Wait();`

Comment: @gunr2171  If I remove the await part, the for loop is executed first and then the ApiRef1() is called which in this case prints the number 20, 20 times.

Comment: @MAK Use a different variable to capture the loop index. i.e. `int j = i; Task.Run(() => ApiRef1(j, log));`

Comment: Remember that "fire and forget" means "I don't care when or even *if* this succeeds". Are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Does the API offers an async version of `ApiRef1`? Since your workload is most probably I/O bound, it will be more scalable to `await` genuine asynchronous methods instead of  blocking thread-pool threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're using an Azure function you cannot have true fire and forget as you risk the function terminating before the completion of all the task(s).

However, we don't care for the result of the task, so we need not await each task individually.

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task> tasks = new System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
  tasks.Add(System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => ApiRef1(i, log));
}
await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

This allows all the tasks to fire in parallel, but pause further execution until they're all complete, ensuring the completion of the tasks before the process is terminated.

Comment: Thank you.  Azure function termination had completely skipped my mind.
I had to assign the value of i to a temporary variable.  Otherwise, the final value of i was being passed to all the function calls.

Comment: See [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/) for why you should always use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew` unless you have a reason not to.

Comment: You can use `Task.WaitAll(tasks)` instead of `Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait()`. But ideally you shouldn't block the thread at all, and use `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` instead.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Interesting. Feel free to update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Task.Run()` returns a `Task`. When you "fire and forget", you don't care about that task.

To take what [DetectivePikachu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609804/fire-and-forget-multiple-methods-in-c-sharp#comment103530255_58609804) suggested, use a discard to ensure that you don't care about the result.

```
public void Run()
{
    ...

    _ = Task.Run(() => ApiRef1(i, log));

    ...
}
```

The method containing the `Task.Run` call is NOT async itself. Unless you have other method calls using `await`, you don't need async anymore.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I did the following:
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
            {
                int j = i;
                _ = Task.Run(() => ApiRef1(j, log));
            }

private static async void ApiRef1(int num, ILogger log)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    log.LogInformation("Number is: " + num);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Please handle exception
                }
            });
            
        }

Comment: @garty I agree. I like your way of handling the tasks. (responding to the comment below)

Comment: Your function will terminate before the 20 tasks have completed.  
(Inadvertently deleted)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the async/Task functionality. Here is one example

```
    public static class AzureFunction
    {
        [FunctionName("SomeAzureFunction")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("*/10 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            Function1(log);
            Function2(log);
            Function3(log);
        }

        private static async void Function1(ILogger log)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(6000);
                log.LogInformation("Function 1 now executed");
            });
        }

        private static async void Function2(ILogger log)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                log.LogInformation("Function 2 now executed");
            });
        }

        private static async void Function3(ILogger log)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                log.LogInformation("Function 3 now executed");
            });
        }
    }
```

(the Threat.Sleep() lines are only there to show you how/that the functions are executed independent from each other)

In the output window you will see that all three functions are started, but Function 3 will finish first (as we do not sleep the thread), then function 2 will finish (as we have a 2 second delay) and at last function 1 will finish (6 seconds delay).

Please notice that all functions in this example have a return type "Void". So this example will only work if you do not care about any return value from the functions.

But I think this comes close to what you asked for

Comment: `async void` is a pretty powerful construct for "fire and forget" functionality

Comment: The Azure Function will terminate before `Function1`, `Function2` and `Function3` have completed execution. As neither of the three functions themselves are awaited the subsequent awaits are redundant, and entierly unnecessary given we care not for the result.